# I cant install Spree gem

Tags: 14.04, gem

Please help me to solve this problem. I have ubuntu 14.04. A new version of ruby.

```
roman@Salomon:~/shopcart$ spree install --auto-accept
     gemfile  spree
     gemfile  spree_gateway
     gemfile  spree_auth_devise
         run  bundle install from "."
/home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/htmlentities-4.3.1/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: duplicated key at line 466 ignored: "inodot"
/home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `each'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:108:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /home/roman/shopcart/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/roman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
roman@Salomon:~/shopcart$
```

and also

```
             run  bundle install from "."
The git source git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
roman@Salomon:~/blog$ bundle install
Updating git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git
Updating git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (= 2.4.3) ruby depends on
      spree_core (= 2.4.3) ruby depends on
        rails (~> 4.1.8) ruby

    rails (4.2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you created your rails app using "rails new my_app" you didn't specify that you want it to use rails *4.1.8*

if it's new application, try `rails _4.1.8_ new my_app`